# Receive data from $POST array

Tags: php

How i can take the data from `test[]` on action.php file?

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test[]"><br />
<input type="text" name="test[]"><br />
<input type="submit" value="invia" />
```

i try this but don't work. How can I print an array in separate data?

```
echo $_POST["test"];
echo $_POST["test"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the index to get the specific items:

```
echo $_POST["test"][0];
echo $_POST["test"][1];
```

Or output the array:

```
print_r($_POST["test"]);
```

Or loop over it:

```
foreach($_POST["test"] as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```